# Diagonal times dense matrix, high precision

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, arbitrary-precision

I have a fixed dense matrix `M` of high precision numbers, say 40 by 40 and precision 40. Then I have a variable vector `v` of the same precision and size. I am interested in the product `N(v) . M`, where `N(v)` is the diagonal matrix with diagonal `v`.

This is the performance critical part of my program, so I want to optimise this as much as possible.

I expected the following to be the fastest:

```
v*M
```

This simple multiplication is identical to the above `N(v).M`.

However, what turns out to be faster is:

```
SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix@v].M
```

I know `SparseArray` is highly optimised, but I'd think that in the more special case where the sparse matrix is diagonal, there might exist something even faster.

So my question is, why is the second line faster than the first, and is there an even faster way?

These are the timings I get:

```
M = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {40}, {40}] // SetPrecision[#, 40] &;
v = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {40}] // SetPrecision[#, 40] &;

Do[v*M, {10^4}] // Timing
Do[SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix@v].M, {10^4}] // Timing
```

gives 8.2 for the first, and 6.4 for the second.